# Operatorvalued valued function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces

in his famous book, Hans Triebel introduce real-valued Sobolev, Sobolev-Slobodeckij-, Besov- and Bessel potential spaces.

Is it possible to define these spaces with values in a Banach space $X$ ($\to$ Bochner spaces), e.g. the Besov space $B^s_{p,q}(\mathbb{R}^n,X)$. Do you know some references?

In several papers i found vectorvalued Sobolev spaces.

Thank you